# rich.table prints unicode when I want ascii

Tags: python, rich

I am trying to print MAC address using python rich library. Below is code. The ":cd" in the MAC address get converted to an actual CD disk emoji. How to prevent that from happening?

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

table = Table(safe_box=True)
table.add_column("MAC address")
table.add_row("08:00:27:cd:af:88")
console = Console()
console.print(table)
```

Output:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ MAC address     ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ 08:00:27af:88 │
└─────────────────┘
```

I tried using safe_box=True option to not print Unicode but that did not work.
I want the final output to look like

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━--━━━━┓
┃ MAC address       ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━--━━┩
│ 08:00:27:cd:af:88 │
└───────────--──────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation describes this.  You use backslash to escape characters that would otherwise be recognized.

```
table.add_row("08:00:27\\:cd:af:88")
```

If you have a string, do

```
s = s.replace(':cd','\\:cd')
```

https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/markup.html

### FOLLOWUP

I looked at the full emoji list in the source code.  There are two possible paths.

First, they look for the Unicode "zero-width joiner" as a way to interrupt the emoji search.  So, you could do:

```
s = s.replace(':cd',':\u200dcd')
```

Second, "cd" is, in fact, the only two-letter emoji code in their list that is also a hex number.  So, you can add this at the top, and this also works:

```
from rich._emoji_codes import EMOJI
del EMOJI["cd"]
```

I've tested both of these.  What a very strange problem.

Comment: ":cd" is just one example. There could be other unicode characters in a MAC address which we cannot predict. Do we look for all of them each time? Is there a more generic solution?

Comment: Sure, you can escape every colon. `s.replace(':','\\:')`

Comment: It did not work for me. I tried table.add_row('08:00:27\\:cd:af:88'), still prints the CD

Comment: I see.  That's contrary to their documentation.  I'll look at the source.

Comment: Its a weird issue indeed. I which there would be some know to just disable unicode. Anyways I found some more emoji codes which could also be hex numbers.
"ab": "",
  "a": "",
    "b": "",

Comment: You do see how to extend my code to include those, right?